# Adding libraries with different versions

Tags: c#, dependencies, version

I have project which is using 2 NuGet dependencies: FreeSpire.Doc and FreeSpire.Xls, both of them have dependency on FreeSpire.Pdf library. The problem is that they dependent on library with different version. And in runtime I've get an exception

> Failed to load type "3" from assembly "Spire.Pdf, Version=3.6.230.55040, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=663f351905198cb3"

Is there a way to have two version of library in project?

Answer (score 0):

AS far as I know you can't have two versions of a NuGet package in the same project.

If the one pointing to the older version **can** work with the newer version, but it'll need to be an ugly hack, such as:

- Manually adding the required DLLs as reference (if's an open source project you might be able to even compile it yourself).
- Seprating the logic to two different projects and always build the one pointing to the newer version after the one pointing to the older version.
- If you can somehow install the DLLs into the GAC, you might be able to run with both versions side-by-side.

Comment: 1. it's not open source; 2. in this case one will still override the other; 3. I can't use GAC because of clickonce deployment do not support it.

Comment: Try creating two projects, one for each package. Compile them and take the assemblies of each package from each of the output folders, but take the shared assembly from the output folder of the project that uses the newer version of it. Finally, add them to the main project as regular references.
It's a hack and you'll need to manually update the assemblies when newer versions of the packages are released, but it might work!